# Guidance Needed For MATLAB MATRIX

Tags: matlab, search, matrix

I am working on a script which takes in array values and generates a matrix as shown in the code. What I want to do, based on below code, is that I want to search another matrix of given values and find the values corresponding to the `cel` and `flr` variables as defined in the program and make a new row to the matrix.

This is the current output:

```
C =

   63.6944   51.7205  -38.2795  -39.0000  -38.0000   B value correspond to -39
  107.5034   68.4665  -21.5335  -22.0000  -21.0000   B value correspond to -22
  155.1031   75.2618  -14.7382  -15.0000  -14.0000   B value correspond to -15
  203.8553   78.8393  -11.1607  -12.0000  -11.0000
  253.0948   81.0307   -8.9693   -9.0000   -8.0000
  302.5838   82.5070   -7.4930   -8.0000   -7.0000
  352.2172   83.5677   -6.4323   -7.0000   -6.0000
  401.9415   84.3662   -5.6338   -6.0000   -5.0000
```

to above I want to add another column which is searching corresponding values in given matrix say `-39`, `-22`, `-15`, `12`, `-9`, `-8`, `-7`, `-6` will be searched in a 2D matrix say `B` which is below. Now I want another column in below matrix which shows corresponding values of the matrix `B` in `A`.

```
B = [-39   14
     -38   12
     -15   10
     -12   17
     -9    45
     -8    16]

a = 1;
for X = [50 100 150 200 250 300 350 400]

   R = hypot(41.4586-2, X);
   theta = atand(X/(41.4586-2));

   dep = theta-90;
   flr = floor(dep);
   Y(row1:col1) = find(Y==flr);
   dB1 = Y(row1:2);

   cel = ceil(dep);
   Y(row2,col2) = find(Y==cel);
   dB2= Y(row2:2);

   A(1,a) = R;
   A(2,a) = theta;
   A(3,a) = dep;
   A(4,a) = flr;
   A(5,a) = cel;
   A(6,a) = dB1;

   a = a+1;

end

C = transpose(A);
```

Comment: so basically, you want to find the smallest value in each row and add the, to that value corresponding value in the B matrix to a new column in A?

Comment: Hi . I want to create a new column in matrix A which has values from matrix B in above code that value will be fed in dB1 to create the matrix new row which will have corresponding  values 14,12,10,17,45,16 .

Comment: = 63.6944 51.7205 -38.2795 -39.0000 -38.0000 14-> value of B in col 2 107.5034 68.4665 -21.5335 -22.0000 -21.0000 12 155.1031 75.2618 -14.7382 -15.0000 -14.0000 10 203.8553 78.8393 -11.1607 -12.0000 -11.0000 17 253.0948 81.0307 -8.9693 -9.0000 -8.0000 45 302.5838 82.5070 -7.4930 -8.0000 -7.0000 16 
This should be output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C =

   63.6944   51.7205  -38.2795  -39.0000  -38.0000   14-> value of B in col 2
  107.5034   68.4665  -21.5335  -22.0000  -21.0000   12
  155.1031   75.2618  -14.7382  -15.0000  -14.0000   10
  203.8553   78.8393  -11.1607  -12.0000  -11.0000   17
  253.0948   81.0307   -8.9693   -9.0000   -8.0000   45
  302.5838   82.5070   -7.4930   -8.0000   -7.0000   16 

this should be the output
```